# How to update antd table with mobx when observable changes

Tags: antd, mobx

my antd table is not updating when `selectedId` property changes:

```
rowClassName={row => row.id === this.model.selectedId
                                    ? row.nameWithTypeAndRunType.type + " " + SELECTED_ROW_CSS_CLASS
                                    : row.nameWithTypeAndRunType.type
                            }
```

i have an workaround, where i extract the table to a constant:

```
const MyTable = (viewModel: MyModel) => (
    <Table<MyModel>
........
```

and add in render() with  `<MyTable {...this.myModel} />`

I'd like to create a RTable, so that i could generally use the antd Table conveniently. I tried this:

```
export function RTable<RecordType extends object = any>(props: TableProps<RecordType>): JSX.Element {
    const t = <Observer>{() => <Table {...props} />}</Observer>
    return t
}
```

Than i use in render() RTable instead of Table tag , but no luck, table does not update.
Any ideas what to do in RTable function to force the update on Table?
Or any other idea how to solve this?

Comment: Would be really cool if you could make some simple reproduction on https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 0):

actually, the problem is that **rowClassName** is a function and mobx can only react to property changes.
So what we did is to pass the **selectedId** as property, so that mobx detects the change and rerenders the component:

```
export interface RTableProperties<RecordType extends object = any> extends TableProps<RecordType> {
    selectedRecordId: string | undefined
}

export function RTable<RecordType extends object = any>(rTableProps: RTableProperties<RecordType>): JSX.Element {
    const rTable = <Table {...rTableProps} />
    return rTable
}
```